# Why doesn't onSensorChanged cause slowdown on the UI thread?

Tags: android

How does the UI manage to be so responsive even when `onSensorChanged()` is called so frequently.  Usually the UI thread executes this method right? Isn't supposed to block other necessary processing while it executes?

Does the UI thread's `Looper` have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the UI manage to be so responsive even when onSensorChanged() is called so frequently.

Because hopefully the logic in `onSensorChanged()` is very very quick. If you do inefficient things in `onSensorChanged()`, your results will be poor.

> Usually the UI thread executes this method right?

Correct.

> Isn't supposed to block other necessary processing while it executes?

Correct.

> Does the UI thread's Looper have anything to do with this?

No more than for any other callback method, where Android calls you on the main application thread.

Comment: Is every activity's method put into uithread's looper.For example: User launched the application - android puts launcher activity's onCreate() in the queue and uithread executes it and similarly onStart() later.What's happening when user touches the screen,does android run'user interface event loop' which puts respective event listener's method into the queue similarly.I can create a new question if this is too much discussion for a comment

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disturb, I saw different answer in a book named "Learn OpenGL ES: For Mobile Game and Graphics Development" - [Link](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=iaC9AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=onSensorchanged%20async%20or%20sync&source=bl&ots=QX2WOk1b8I&sig=ACfU3U3N93LSrp6MLbDe9n6otkfo7Ay48A&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_l-T7zMnqAhWu-GEKHf1WCXwQ6AEwAnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) - which says "In the Android Sensor API, the callback method onSensorChanged requests data in an async manner, so the UI thread is not blocked while waiting for a piece of data"